# MongoDB (spring) Criteria - check if there is nested object with properties

Tags: spring, mongodb

my data strucutre look like this:

```
Teams:
{ name:"team1",
  users:[
     {
     age:45,
     licence:true
     },
     {
     age:70,
     licence:false
     }
 ]
},
..other teams..
```

I want to return teams with at least one person = 70years old who has licence.
My current code looks like this:

```
criteria = Criteria.where("user.age").(70).and("user.licence").is(true)
Query q = new Query(criteria);
... perform q ...
```

The problem is that this kind of criteria recognize if there exist somone = 70 AND somone with licence (not somone with licence and 70 at the same time) so in my case it would return true even though its not. Im not sure how can i perform this kind of (simple) query. I was looking for it in documentation but no successes :(

Comment: you can use [$elemMatch](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) operator, to match both condition in same element, you can use same operator in projection as well to return single element in array. i don't know how to do in spring.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$elemMatch` operator to match multiple fields of a subdocument in a subdocument array.

### Raw query

```
{
  "users": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "age": 70,
      "licence": true
    }
  }
}
```

### Spring criteria

```
      Criteria.where("users")
        .elemMatch(Criteria.where("age").is(70).and("licence").is(true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use addCriteria(...) method

In your case :

```kotlin
val query = Query(
                Criteria.where("users.age").isEqualTo(70)
        ).addCriteria(
                Criteria.where("users.licence").isEqualTo(false)
        )

//Then perform query
```

Sorry for it not being in plain Java. But shouldn't be hard to get turn it into it